# How can have an argument to a function be a type? (Similar to va_arg's second argument)

Tags: c, variadic-functions, variadic, variadic-macros

In the function va_arg for variadic functions, the second argument is just 'type'. When using this function, examples pass something like 'int'. How can I pass and use types in functions of my own? For example if I wanted to malloc a block of memory so that using brackets [ ] will use the correct offsets to what the user specified, is there a way to do this?

Comment: `va_arg` is not a function but a macro, and this is typically how all such things are accomplished.  They're usually not a good idea unless you have a very specific reason to want to do this, and a clear understanding of the language to know exactly what you are doing.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by your last sentence.  Can you add a specific example of what you want to be able to do?

Comment: If I malloc a block, whatever I cast the pointer to will dictate where in memory an offset such as [1] or [2] return. If I want the user to be able to pass either a type or a number of bytes to use, is there any way to compute offsets in memory using brackets, or is the only way to use pointer arithmetic?

Comment: @nevets Using brackets **is** pointer arithmetic.  `A[B]` is exactly equivalent to `*(A + B)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions can't. `va_arg` is a macro that invokes a lot of platform specific junk. But what you want to do might look something like this:

```
#define mallocT(T, n) (malloc(sizeof(T) * (n)))
```

where T is the type argument and n is the array size integer argument.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: You could, but should you?  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc